# How to get a Material-UI password input in React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm using Material-UI and React Testing Library in a project and I'm having a hard time with TextField that is set to `type="password"`. I understand that, in tests, it's not a good practice to default to getting an element using `testId` field, but I cannot find a way to get to the password input field. I cannot use `getByRole` because apparently `<input type="password">` doesn't have a role. There is no text in the input box, nor placeholder text, and when I try to use `getByLabelText` I'm getting this error message:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Found a label with the text of: Password, however no form control was found associated to that label. Make sure you're using the "for" attribute or "aria-labelledby" attribute correctly.
```

When I reviewed the rendered elements in the test (I used `screen.debug()`), I realize that this is how Material-UI composes the TextField:

```html
<div>
  <div
      class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth"
    >
    <label
      class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated"
      data-shrink="false"
    >
      Password
    </label>
    <div
      class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInput-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl"
    >
      <input
        aria-invalid="false"
        class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input"
        name="pass"
        type="password"
        value=""
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, the `<input>` is not embedded inside the `<label>` and also the label doesn't have a `for` attribute to associate it with the input. So, how else would I be able to get a hold of that password box without using `testId`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to set the `id` prop to `TextField` for it to associate the label to the input

Comment: How would this look? I tried passing this to `SelectProps` and `MenuProps` without luck